# Fill Irregular Shape with Squares without Overlap

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization, bin-packing

I have irregular shapes (think geographic boundaries) that I need to fill with a set of differently sized squares, without overlap. Priority should be placed on using the largest square possible. My approach thus far is to loop over the length/width of the image at an increment and check if a square at that (x,y) is valid. If so, save the square there and mark the region as invalid. I then repeat the process for each square size I have. It does what I want but is far too slow for practically small increments. If I try to do it in one pass using else/if on each square dimension, the smallest square will dominate. I also have no guarantee of optimality regarding square size.

```
nim[mask] = .5
nim[~mask] = 0
cim = nim.copy()

inc = 500
dims = [4000, 2000, 1000, 500]

regions = []
for d in dims:
    for x in range(0, nim.shape[0], inc):
        for y in range(0, nim.shape[1], inc):
            if (np.count_nonzero(cim[x:x+d, y:y+d])/(d*d) < .0001):
                nim = rect(nim, y, x, d, d, 1)
                cim = blocc(cim, y, x, d, d, 1)
                regions.append([x,y,d])
                
plt.imshow(nim)
plt.show()
```

Where rect() and blocc() draw the sides of the region and the filled region, respectively.

[image: Desired result]

Comment: It's always hard to know whether the example you've shown represents what you're actually trying to do. Phrases like *"far too slow for practically small increments"* are especially worrisome. What is a practically small increment? `dims` has four elements. How many elements does `dims` have in the real problem? Is too slow measured in milliseconds, seconds, or hours?

Comment: Finally, the sample map shows lots of imagination. Imagination is easy for humans, but expensive for a computer. To understand the problem from a computer's point of view, consider just the four largest squares. Move the leftmost and rightmost squares down one position. Move the bottom-left square three units to the right. Now you've got the four largest squares on a nice simple grid. Not very imaginative, but a good start for a simple algorithm. Is imagination a requirement, or just a nicety?

Comment: Practically small increment refers to the inc variable, which is how 'fast' it moves over the image; more precisely it is the number of pixels it skips in each dimension x,y. A larger increment limits precision because it is only testing a subset of locations rather than each pixel. Dims can have any number of elements, though four or five seem appropriate. As far as you comments about imagination, I do not totally know what you mean. I want as much of the area in as large as square possible, the smaller squares are to get what the larger ones a cannot due to the irregular shape.

Comment: Four or five is reasonable. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBdOJ.png) of a solution with no imagination. Is that good enough?

Comment: That looks great! I am more concerned with the runtime than anything else, how did you make that?

Comment: That was drawn by hand following a simple set of rules. I'll post a full answer in bit. But the quick summary is: A) create a grid of the largest squares, B) find a good position for that grid, C) subdivide the squares that aren't fully inside the shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach to the problem is to:
A) create a grid of the largest squares
B) find a good position for the grid, and
C) subdivide the squares that aren't fully inside the shape.

The first step is to overlay the shape with a grid of the largest squares. An example of this is shown below. Green squares are fully within the shape, yellow squares are partially outside the shape, and red squares are fully outside the shape.

[image]

The second step is to find the optimal placement for the grid. Defining the smallest square as 1x1 units, and the largest square as 8x8 units, there are 64 possible placements for the grid. The best placement for the grid maximizes the number of green squares. Given two placements that have an equal number of green squares, the criteria for choosing the better placement would be

- minimize the number of yellow squares, or
- put the green squares roughly at the center of the shape

Once the grid placement has been settled, green squares are kept as is, red squares are discarded, and yellow squares are subdivided into four smaller squares. Here's an example of a yellow square being subdivided:

[image]

The same rules apply: keep the green, discard red, subdivide yellow. The process of subdividing squares continues recursively until the smallest size square is reached.

The final result looks like this:

[image]